# converting BR tags into new lines in a textarea

Tags: php, html, textarea

This is a function I made which is supposed to convert every `Br` line break into a `\n`:

```
function br2nl($st){
    return preg_replace('/<br(\s+)?\/?>/i', "\n", $st);
}
```

However, the output is like this:

```
foo

bar

nuts
```

I want it to output something like:

```
foo <br>
bar <br>
nuts
```

Comment: You actually want to replace multiple occurrences of <br> with just ONE '\n'? E.g. to replace two adjacent <br><br> with one new line character??? If there is just one <br> tag between your words, function will work, btw... (no empty spaces).

Comment: show your html code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your HTML is

```
foo<br>
bar<br>
nuts<br>
```

So you already have "\n" and replacing **br** to "\n" you ends up with double "\n" like

```
foo \n\n bar \n\n nuts
```

it's looks like

```
foo

bar

nuts
```

For receiving output you suggest - you need to remove "\n" from the input HTML  and then replace **br** to "\n"

The code would be

```
function br2nl($st){
  $st_no_lb = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $st );
  return preg_replace('/<br(\s+)?\/?>/i', "\n", $st_no_lb);
}
```